# How to ArrayAdapter mixed add item?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a ArrayAdapter. I want to item with mixed. For example;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>();

Adapter.add("Table");
Adapter.add("Desk");
Adapter.add("Pen");
Adapter.add("Computer");
Adapter.add("Mouse");
Adapter.add("Book");
```

I am adding items my ArrayAdapter. But I want to after adding, I add other item on under "Pen" item. For example;

```
Adapter.add("New Item");
```

But this item is last. I want to this item is adding under "Pen" item. How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert(T object, int index)` instead. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html